# How do I refer to a .zip file in Terraform Settings block locally, instead of using a URL

Tags: terraform

I have a settings block in terraform, right now it refers a .zip file and uses the url field to refer to it. How can I refer to the .zip file locally?

PS the module is in GitHub and also available locally

Thanks

code example: (Settings block is from terraform azure vm extension)

```
settings = <<SETTINGS
{
  "Wmfversion": "latest",
  "Configuration":
        {
           "url": "https://....github/CreateADRootDC1.ps1.zip"
        "script": "CreateADRootDC1.ps1",
      "function": "CreateADRootDC1"   
               },
  }

can I refer to the file with this syntax "source:" = "./modules/addsvms/DSC/CreateADRootDC1.ps1.zip",
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to give a more complete example, such as shown in the [mcve] guide please? It's very hard to understand what you're trying to achieve here as it stands.

Comment: sorry how do I edit the question? I was trying the code didn't paste properly sorry

Comment: Click the `edit` button below your post or [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60114948/edit)

Comment: found it thanks, I tried to format but settings block format changes after I post it here... it's in HCL (Terraform)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a blob storage to achieve this:

```
"url" = "https://foo.blob.core.windows.net/dsc.zip" <<< get zip from this url and unzip it to a special folder on the vm
"script" = "configure.ps1" <<< load this file into memory
"function" = "AzureDscDemo" <<< call this function from inside the file
```